# How to turn flashlight on/off using one button?

Tags: ios

I can turn my flashlight on with one button and turn it off with another. But I want to do it with only one button. However, I don't have a framework which allows me to use the bool isSelected method. So I'm quite clueless on how to merge both functions together in one button.

Here's the code which works:

```
-(void)onButtonPressed 
{

AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice 
defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight
isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
{
    BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if(success){
        [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}

}
```

I use this to turn the flashlight off.

```
-(void)offButtonPressed {

AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice
defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight
isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
{
    BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if(success){
        [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}


}
```

I'm not particular about the way it's done. As long as the flashlight turns on with the first tap and turns off on the second, I couldn't care less about the method.

However, I'm using barbuttonitems made programatically, so please don't give me IBAction methods. I'd also appreciate it if the method suggested is as simple as possible, I think the way I'm using the flashlight right now is overly complex.

Comment: A UISwitch comes to mind, would that meet your requirements?

Comment: That would be fine, but how do I make it on a toolbar overlay? Remember that I have to make it programmatically.

Comment: Ah, I have a better idea. What if you created a counter in your class, the first time you press the button it increases the counter to 1 (On) the second time it resets it to 0 (Off) then you can do an if else statement and execute your flashlight on/off code. This way you could remove your other button. Let me know if that works for you and I can add it as an answer for you to accept and resolve this question.

Comment: That sounds wonderful in theory, but how exactly would I create the counter. I understand what you're saying, but can you use the code I've put here to demonstrate?

Comment: Sure give me a second to write it up as an answer, I'll be making a few assumptions so just let me know if something is inaccurate to your situation.

Comment: No problem, I can't believe I didn't think of it before. It's a brilliant solution, however I've never implemented it that too in this type of context.

Answer (score 30):

I've just implemented this feature on my app. Answering your question, here is how to merge both functions in one method.

```
- (void) flashlight
{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (success) 
        {
            if ([flashLight isTorchActive]) {
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            } else {
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            }
            [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For swift 3

```
@IBAction func toggleFlash() {
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo), device.hasTorch {
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        let torchOn = !device.isTorchActive
        try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0)
        device.torchMode = torchOn ? .on : .off
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Statement :**

---

### Turn on and off flashlight on your mobile device (iOS Supported) using a single button.

**Solution** :

1. Create a button on View Controller.
2. Set button action and add target
   as self.

> **NOTE :** Set tag as 101 in interface builder before executing, this will initiate the tag value as 101.

Below is the code which should be written in action method in your ***ViewController.m*** file

---

```
- (IBAction)flashLightButtonTapped:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *button = sender;
    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if (button.tag==101)
    {

        if ([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
        {
            BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (success)
            {
                if ([flashLight isTorchActive])
                {
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                }
                else
                {
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                }
                [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
        button.tag=102;
    }
    else if (button.tag==102)
    {
        if ([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
        {
            BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (success)
            {
                if ([flashLight isTorchActive])
                {
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                }
                else
                {
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];

                }
                [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
        button.tag=101;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going of off comments here, this is what I was thinking:

```
.h

@property (nonatomic) int flashlightState;

.m

-(void) viewDidLoad:
{
    //Any previous code that you may have
    flashlightState = 0;
}
-(void) flashlightStateControl:
{

    if (flashlightState == 1)
    {
        offButtonPress();
        flashlightState = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        onButtonPress();
        flashlightState = 1;
    }
}
```

The idea being that instead of what you have been calling, you now call `flashlightStateControl()`. That should do what you wanted, you are more than welcome to tweak parts of it(you may need to), but that is the general idea in code form. Hope that works out for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tweaked till no end, but gave up after a while. I'd greatly appreciate if you answer my new question. Ever since you've given me the idea of a switch, I decided to use that instead of a barbuttonitem. It's so much more enhancing of an app's quality.

Comment: @AndrewLaeddis Hmm, I wonder what part of it didn't work, that above code should do what you wanted it to. In any case, be sure to resolve this question by either deleting it or accepting this answer. I've also put in an answer to your new question, I hope that works better for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)flash:(UIButton *)sender;
{
    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff) {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                //TorchIsOn = YES;

                [self.flashton setHighlighted:YES];
            } else {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                //TorchIsOn = NO;

                [self.flashton setHighlighted:NO];
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Swift 5** based on Chuy47's answer:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

extension AVCaptureDevice {

    /// toggles the device's flashlight, if possible
    static func toggleFlashlight() {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video), device.hasTorch else { return }
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            let torchOn = !device.isTorchActive
            try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
            device.torchMode = torchOn ? .on : .off
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Error toggling Flashlight: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 version**

```
@IBAction func toggleTorch() {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video), device.hasTorch else {
        showTorchNotSupported()
        return
    }
    
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        let torchOn = !device.isTorchActive
        try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
        device.torchMode = torchOn ? .on : .off
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        showTorchNotSupported()
    }
}

private func showTorchNotSupported() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Flashlight is not supported", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Understand", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```