# IOS8 torch turns on when dark, inspite of setting AVCaptureTorchModeOff

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

used below code to disable torch was working fine in ios7 ,
but in ios8 torch gets on when dark

```
 AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
                    if ([device hasTorch] || [device hasFlash]){
                        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
                        [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                        [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                        [device unlockForConfiguration];
                    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14740500/1106035

Comment: Did you managed to turn it off in iOS 8

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it works...

```
 - (IBAction)flashOnClicked:(id)sender
    {
        AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
        {
            BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (success)
            {
                if ([flashLight isTorchActive])
                {
                    //TURN ON
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                }
                else
                {
                    //TURN OFF
                    [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                }
                [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not working its entering success status but still the light gets on